# How can I prevent from someone to run my PHP file directly a million times

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

*Hey , 
I have finished developing my app 
In my iphone apps I have a string (created by user)
And a button ,
When button is touched the php is activated with the user given string
How can I prevent from someone to run my PHP file directly a million times with diffrentes string each time ?

Is that possible ? How ?
This is importment because php file activating MySQL query insert command .

Comment: So you are calling a PHP script from Objective-C or something? Your question is too vague. Show us some code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many ways, but the simplest would be to increment a counter that you store in the session variable for each request and show a reject page when the counter hits a certain number.

This means, of course, that you're trusting the client to use the same session id for each request.  If you're willing to do a bit more work, then make the app send in the device UUID with each request (and reject request that don't include it), and base your counter on the UUID.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't really matter if the code is run 1 million times, but, if it does matter to you, here's what you can do:

Store the IP address of the user in another database. Delete entries after 1 hour or so, then if there are over 100 (or however many) entries from that IP address, refuse to run the other PHP code until an hour has passed and the other entries have been deleted from the database.

Comment: It should really matter. Think of the performance hit of a very expensive query. Take API's for an example. Imagine if Google didn't have limits on their API's.

Comment: He said you have to push a button. There will be not a lot of performance drop if they have to push the button each time and submit the form, since each request will take some time. But point taken, if he has 1 million users.

Comment: There are plenty of malicious people on the web who could write a script to push the button form them at a rate of hundreds of times per second. It's a shame, but you've always got to be thinking of what the most evil user might try to do.

Comment: Yes, it is a shame. If he gets enough interest in his app, there will always be some malicious interest.

Comment: Thanks man thats helped me a lot but hat is someone blocking his IP ?